# Laravel errors while storing a file

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a laravel crud project. Now i want to store files like .xlsx and .docx
But i keep getting errors in my controller and browser:

Controller:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'description_short'=>'',
            'description_long'=>'',
            'file'=>'',
            'language_id'=> [
                'required', 'exists:language,id'
            ],
        ]);
        $fileName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filePath = 'files/' . $fileName;
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($request->file));
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->url($path);

        $file = new File([
            'title'=> $request->get('title'),
            'description_short'=> $request->get('description_short'),
            'description_long'=> $request->get('description_long'),
            'file'=>$request->get('file'),
            'language_id'=> $request->language_id,
        ]);
        $file->save();
       
        return back();
    }
```

Here i get the error: Undefined method 'url'

Create page:

```
     <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.language.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
          <div class="form-group">    
              <label for="title">{{('name')}}</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="value">{{('file')}}</label>
              <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file"/>
          </div>        
     
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add language</button>
      </form>
```

the browser error i get is : Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string.

if i need to provide more information i will gladly do so!

Comment: Does this help - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-urls? I reckon it's relevant to the misuse of `Storage::disk('public')->url($path);`.

Answer (score 0):

`file` is reserved keyword in `Request class` to get submitted Files in post method.

You can not use `file` in input. So first you have to change file name in input box.

After that you can do like below.

`$request->file('file_input_name')->getClientOriginalName();`

Comment: this did not solve the problem. i still get the same problems as before

Comment: is that same error or you got some new kind of error

Comment: i got the same error but i fixed it by doing this:
         $file = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
```

fixed it